# Postgresql package not found in ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04

04 and rolling out my pc as openstreetmap server. I needed to install postgresql and postgis packages for the same. i used

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib postgis postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1
```

and it showed

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1'
```

Please help. How do I move ahead?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 15.04 has PostgreSQL version 9.4. So it should work if you change the `9.3` to `9.4`, try again with:

```
$ sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib postgis postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.1
```